# ExtJS 4 Problem with MVC concept

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

i'm trying to use the new MVC concept and therefore started witht the AccountManager Example (examples/simple). Everything works fine as far as I stick to the tutorial, but I tried to extend it a bit.

I define a border layout in 'Viewport.js' and assign a header component (views/Header.js) to 'north'
and a tab-Panel (views/MainPanel.js) which contains the 'views/user/List.js' as a tab.

Until now everything is ok.

But now i added another store (Profiles.js) and model (Profile.js),
changed the references in code to use profile-store instead of user-store.
I also updated the column-definition, imports ('requires') and everything es that is relevant(at least i think so...).

When i run my app i get a js-error in Observable.js -> addManagedListener-> 'item is undefined' when he tries to invoce the on-method of 'item'.

At first i tried hard to find the mistake i made in the code but I could not find anything,
so i started to play around a little bit and found out,
that it works as soon as I rename the folder 'user' in views/ to 'profile' (of course i had to fix some references in code too).

Is this behavior a bug or is it volitional?
If so can anybody please tell me how this is exactly working?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i had to give my controller a reference to the store and the model.
I didn't do that from the beginning, after my controller had a reference to the view, the view had a reference to the store and the store had a reference to the model.
So I assumed everything is ok.

But it seems to be mandatory to provide this information redundant as far as understand and i can live with that...

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS looks for the Javascript files based on your model/view/controller declarations.

i.e. if in your *tell* your controller that you have a store called Profile (via the `stores` attribute) by default, it is going to look for a file at `app_name/stores/Profile.js`